# Sort By Column in Jupyter notebook

Tags: unix, jupyter-notebook

I have searched and read many examples about sorting by column in Jupyter Notebook. And I use all the answers but i get the same error.

Input file specified two times.

I'm using windows operatings system 10. I have Jupyter notebook and UNIX install (git bash).

I have tried a lot of results by searching online in stackoverflow. But for me just doesnt work i dont know what I can do wrong.

I tried the following

a) `!head -n 6 $filename | sort -f -t ' ' -k2`

b) `sort -f -t '' k2 $filename`

c) `sort -k1,1 -k4,4n $filename`

If I write my code like `!head -n 4 $filename | sort`.
It works first lines are sorted as should.
But when I want to sort by column and I use the codes listed above I always get the following error:

> Input file specified two times